# How to determine the Encryption Algorithm for Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.Cryptography.CryptographyClient.Decrypt on Keys

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, cryptography, azure-keyvault

The [`CryptographyClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.keys.cryptography.cryptographyclient?view=azure-dotnet) requires `EncryptionAlgorithm` for the [`Decrypt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.keys.cryptography.cryptographyclient.decryptasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Security_KeyVault_Keys_Cryptography_CryptographyClient_DecryptAsync_Azure_Security_KeyVault_Keys_Cryptography_EncryptionAlgorithm_System_Byte___System_Threading_CancellationToken_) operation. How can I determine what to use for a Self-Signed Key I created in `OpenSSL` or whatever for whatever key?

The `EncryptionAlgorithm` offers `enum`  values of

1. `Rsa15`
2. `RsaOaep`
3. `RsaOaep256`

How do I choose out of the above if I already created Self-Signed `RSA` Key using `OpenSSL`?

Comment: You can use your pre-generated RSA key for all offered encryption types. You should leave out the (older) Rsa15-variant and instead use the newer OAEP ones. That's because OAEP adds a random element that makes the encryption non-determistic. more information e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51073259/difference-between-rsa-oaep-and-rsa-pkcs1-5/51090609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those algorithms are encryption algorithms, not key types. Which you should use depends on your application. `Rsa15` (algorithm "RSA1_5") is old and not recommended for secure applications. `RsaOaep` (algorithm "RSA-OAEP") is probably more prolific but uses SHA-1 to hash, so `RsaOaep256` (algorithm (RSA-OAEP-256) is more secure since it uses SHA-256.

You can read about these algorithms from various sources including Wikipedia.

In the Key Vault SDK for C#, we also support those algorithms locally if you have the key material (like public key for encryption) locally, since those same algorithms are supported locally. Some algorithms may not always be supported, like EC keys on .NET Framework 4.6.1 which will throw a `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: I am using Key Vault itself to `decrypt` , so it's essentially advisable for end-users to use Key Vault to `encrypt` instead of using their own code to do so. This will give high chances of getting accurate values?

Comment: Encrypting only requires a public key, so you can do that client-side. In fact, the `CryptographyClient` will attempt to cache key material, and currently that includes only the public key retrieved from Key Vault or Managed HSM. The encryption algorithm support is industry standard, so you'll always get compatible results regardless of local or remote via Key Vault or another service.